# 5 star rating with jquery gives an Unexpected string

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.star').mouseover(function (){
    var star = $(this).index()1;
    $(this).parent().css("background-position","0 -" (32 * star) "px");
});

$('.star-rating').mouseout(function (){
    var originalresult = $(this).attr('id').split('result')[1];
    $(this).css("background-position","0 -" (32 * originalresult) "px");
});
```

Don't get this, rewriting is giving me stars in my eyes, but the problem stands... Don't know anymore what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add the pluses in between and move the -ve sign inside the bracket = "0" + (-32 * star) + "px". Likewise for the mouseout function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var star = $(this).index()1;` there is an extra 1 at the end.

`$(this).parent().css("background-position","0 -" (32 * star) "px");`
`$(this).css("background-position","0 -" (32 * originalresult) "px");`
All the string concatenation should be joined with `+`;

Comment: Got it, but it's still gives me an error Unexpected string..?

Comment: See the updated. Usually the unexpected string error means there is some syntax error.